# Calling std::move() on derefrence value of smart pointer

Tags: c++

```
class A{
public:
  void AddObject(MsgType msg){
    msg_queue.push_back(msg);
  }
private:
 std::queue<MsgType> msg_queue;
}
```

I have this class A and its method `AddObject()`. There are 2 types of clients for this class. First type is where they get only `boost::sharedPtr<MsgType>` and other client has `std::shared_ptr<MsgType>` or `const MsgType&`.

What should be signature of `AddObject()` so that I can avoid conversion or making copy here. If I use `AddObject(MsgType msg)` then I will have to call from client side:

```
boost::shared_ptr<MsgType> msg;
AddObject(std::move(*msg));
```

or

```
std::shared_ptr<MsgType> msg;
AddObject(std::move(*msg));
```

and I can use `std::move()` in `AddObject()` to store it in queue. 
Considering performance, what should be my API here?

Size of MsgType is around 1.4 MB which is protobuf message. For protobuf move costructors are very costly. So looks like I cannot use std::move here.

Comment: Can you add more code to clarify the problem? In particular, what is the MsgType object? Is it cheap to move but expensive to copy?

Comment: @SergeyA I have added more details.

Comment: I don't follow - you ask about a `std::move` solution but then reject it for being too costly. How is it costly? What then do you actually want to know?

Comment: It seems you want to take an ownership from `shared_ptr`. Is `MsgType` actually shared between different users? And what should they do after `AddObject` is called?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am looking for the best solution here. What should be my API

Comment: Best solution by what measure? What is your goal? What are your constraints? What do you want to do?

Comment: Using `std::move` on the object managed by a `shared_ptr` is not a good idea, whether you do it on the client side or within your function. What if there are other `shared_ptr`s referring to the same object? If shared ownership for that object is necessary, the right answer might be to make a copy. As the other commenters have already said, it's difficult to answer your question without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have originally written `AddObject()`, it makes no assumptions about the ownership of the input `MsgType`.  It doesn't know, or care, how the `MsgType` is allocated, or who should own it.  In that scenario, the only valid thing you can do is make a copy for yourself, which is what you currently do.

If you want `AddObject()` to take ownership without making a copy, then `AddObject()` needs to be explicit about how it expects ownership to be managed.  You express ownership semantics in one of two ways:

- require exclusive ownership by using `std::unique_ptr` (or `boost::unique_ptr`):

  ```
  class A{
  public:
    void AddObject(std::unique_ptr<MsgType> msg){
      msg_queue.push(std::move(*msg));
    }
  private:
    std::queue<MsgType> msg_queue;
  };
  ```

  Or better:

  ```
  class A{
  public:
    void AddObject(std::unique_ptr<MsgType> msg){
      msg_queue.push(std::move(msg));
    }
  private:
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<MsgType>> msg_queue;
  };
  ```
- share ownership by using `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`):

  ```
  class A{
  public:
    void AddObject(std::shared_ptr<MsgType> &msg){
      msg_queue.push(msg);
    }
  private:
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<MsgType>> msg_queue;
  };
  ```

Otherwise, all you can really do is `std::move()` the *contents* of the input `MsgType`, and then let the caller worry about deallocating the `MsgType` later on:

```
class A{
public:
  void AddObject(MsgType &msg){
    msg_queue.push(std::move(msg));
  }
private:
  std::queue<MsgType> msg_queue;
};
```

However, in your situation, this last option is probably not very viable since you claim that moving a protobuf object is costly.  In that case, you should move around just a pointer to a protobuf object rather than moving around the object itself.  That is where `(std|boost)::unique_ptr` and `(std|boost)::shared_ptr` come into play.

If you want to code your class to support both `std` and `boost` smart pointers, then you will have to either overload `AddObject()` for each type, or give it a template parameter that you can specialize on as needed.